# How to remove css background-color from Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap applies a background-color: transparent on a table

```
table {
   max-width: 100%;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

and I want to remove this rule on only one page. I can't add a style tag on table because I don't have access to it. I was thinking to use Jquery :

```
$('table').css('background-color', '')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: why not add a class? `$('table').addClass('no-background');`

Comment: Do you not have access to any css style sheets that are loaded by that page?

Comment: @AndrewLeedham I can edit all styles

Comment: @Sysix ok but what should I do to remove entirely the rule ? In the browser I just have to uncheck the box. What is the equivalent in css ?

Comment: Override the style using `background-color: initial;`

Comment: var t = document.getElementsByTagName("table"); t.style.removeProperty("background-color");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS on same page.

```
<style> table{background-color: #FDE5DD !important;} </style>
```

Or you can do this using JQuery

```
 <script> 

      $(document).ready(function(){    
      $('table').css('background-color', 'red');    
       )};

</script>
```

Comment: It works but not really because the background color applies on every table of the page and I have only one table I have to apply this rule. And it's a table I can't add a style or a class